# React : Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, render

I have a component that looks like this

```
function FirstCollapse(data, basis, comparisonMode, heading, referenceData, locations, expandAll) {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useRowStyles();

    const innerHeadings = Object.keys(referenceData[heading]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpen(expandAll);
    }, [expandAll]);

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
         <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          {
           (heading !== "NPU Resources") ?  
              innerHeadings.map((innerHeading, index) => {
                return(
                   <>
                    {InnerCollapse(data, basis, comparisonMode, heading, innerHeading, referenceData, locations, innerHeadings, index, expandAll)}
                   </>);
              })
            : NPUResourceTable(data, basis, comparisonMode, locations, expandAll)           
          }
         </Collapse>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

The NPUResourceTable function looks something like this:

```
export default function NPUResourceTable(data, basis, comparisonMode, locations, expandAll) {

    try {
        const innerHeadings = getAllHWResources(data, locations);
        return(
            <>
                {
                    innerHeadings.map((innerHeading, index) => {
                        return(
                            <>
                                {InnerCollapse(data, basis, comparisonMode, locations, innerHeading, index, innerHeadings, expandAll)}
                            </>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </>
        );
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return(<InfoAlert contentText={dataErrorText} />);
    }
}
```

The getAllHwResources function is as follows

```
function getAllHWResources(data, locations) {

    const allResources = new Set();

    data.map(snapShot => {
        [...locations].map(loc => {
             allResources.add(dataPoint[someKey]);
        })

    })
    return [...allResources];
}
```

The data variable is an array of objects. The object might have variable keys and innerHeadings is basically the union of all unique keys and might change as we add new objects to the data variable.

What to do in this case

I tried resolving it through various ways but failed.

Comment: Try to remove try catch block in NPUResourceTable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.